# Don't tell me that I get privileges on Teams—maybe it shouldn't even have the concept of privileges in the first place

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-for-teams

I joined the Teams group for SmokeDetector/Charcoal today. Looking at the privileges page, **every privilege, other than bounties, only needs 1 reputation:**

[image: All privileges take only 1 reputation, except for bounties, which need 75]

However, I got three notifications about privileges today, a few hours after joining the team:

[image: I was notified of getting the ability to edit posts, cast close/reopen votes, and use trusted user tools]

This is weird; everyone starts with these, so why should I get a notification for them (and only some of them)? This is strange, to be notified of things that I didn't actually earn.

Additionally, if only one privilege actually takes reputation, **why should there be privileges at all?** Because Stack Overflow for Teams likely is used by a lot of people who've never used Stack Overflow, this could be a weird, confusing thing. Instead, there should just be something like [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) but more detailed, going over what all these privileges do.

Just a feature request in the form of a few random thoughts.

Comment: Maybe all teams are not set at one rep for everything. Your survey set is currently one team isn't it?

Comment: @RobertLongson As far as I'm aware, Teams reputation levels aren't configurable.

Comment: Two privileges requires rep. Downvotes still require 125 rep, in spite of it not being listed

Comment: Privileges can be useful for some Teams. Our team is pretty big with lot of questions that are specific to the group. However, since there are a lot of members that can join every year, we cannot trust them blindly. Configure the required reputation for privileges would be a great benefit for our team.

Answer (score 3):

You're absolutely correct! We are thinking about it; we know it is a problem, and we are thinking of ways to solve this, but it's not going to be resolved in the near term.